# Windows 10 Unable to access xxx.local domain via nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting an error on my Windows machine but not my mac on the same network. Any idea?

```
(node:16940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at E:\xxx.js:28:47
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:16940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 
2)
(node:16940) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

```
function checkNumSatoshis(JWTToken, qrcode) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get(
        `http://xxx.local/api/v1/xx/xx/invoice?paymentRequest=${qrcode}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `JWT ${JWTToken}`,
          },

        }
      )
      .then((res) => resolve(res.data.xx))
      .catch((error) => reject(error.response.data))
  });
}
```

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/)

Comment: The problem is with the `res`, you are not getting it from the request. A simple fix can be `res?.data`

Comment: I think windows just doesnt like .local domain? Not getting any data from the request

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in setting up the request, so the promise goes to the catch block.  However, `error.response` is `undefined` because there is no request being made.

Do the following instead to get more information about this error:

```
 .catch((error) => { console.log(error)})
```

Comment: Thanks. Windows just doesn't like .local domain: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80. Do you know how to bypass? xxx.local domain is NOT 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I've added xxx.local 192.168.1.xx to C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc\hosts but it didn't work. I can browse to it but not via nodejs

Comment: Try using postman and request the data from the API and see if there is an error.

Comment: all ok via Postman. I think axios may not like xxx.local domain which is not local. It can't resolve it.

Comment: Example, the API server is not on 127.0.0.1 but it's resolving to it on Windows machine. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80,
  config: {
    url: 'xxx.local/api/v1/lnd/xx/invoice?paymentRequest=xxx',
    method: 'get',

Answer (score 0):

Add 192.168.1.x xx.local to your C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc\hosts fixed. I entered the correct format in the host file